# Update prettify to include new languages available (for example XQuery)

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

[Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) has a [bunch of more languages plugins available](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src) than Stack Overflow uses, [among them one for XQuery](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-xq.js).

I guess that Stack Exchange wants to keep the JavaScript size low and thus leaves out some rarely used languages. While [xquery](/questions/tagged/xquery) seems to be a less important tag (only something around 1k questions with that tag), it is also able to highlight [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) correctly (which is a subset of XQuery) that has much more impact. Together their use is comparable to the one of [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell), which *is* included.

And both XQuery and XPath highlightings are *very, very broken* at the moment – they use lots of `//` tokens in regular code statements, so we've got lots of false comments in there. For example:

```xq
for $node in //*[attribute()]
return local-name($node)
```

There are lots of `<!-- language: lang-none -->` blocks in lots of posts, and barely all others should be edited to include it as the wrong highlighting really hurts your eyes.

Comment: Hmm, that's still 22kb compressed, that's a lot of extra JS to be sending to the vast majority of users who won't benefit...you're right in assuming that's what we weigh when including these language plugins.

Comment: This is mainly for all the function in Marklogic's namespaces that also got included. This regular expression will strip it down to a third of it's size, only leaving standard: `((xinc|xhtml|xdmp|trgr|xp|sec|spell|thsr|search|prof|ppt|pki|cts|alert|kml|pdf|p|msword|mcgm|ooxml|mamamamamamamalnk|lnk|gml|geo|georss|feed|dom|dls|dbg|cvt|css|cpf):[-\w]+\|)`. I guess one could improve even further by optimizing the regular expression (or making it a little bit more fuzzy and match everything as a function that looks like one).